# sort.SearchInts works strangely or I'm missing something

Tags: go

Consider the following example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    var n int
    var a sort.IntSlice
    a = append(a, 23)   
    a = append(a, 3)
    a = append(a, 10)
    sort.Sort(a)    
    fmt.Println(a)
    n = sort.SearchInts(a, 1)
    fmt.Println(n)
    n = sort.SearchInts(a, 3)
    fmt.Println(n)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/wo4r43Zghv

And the result is:

```
[3 10 23]
0
0
```

How am I supposed to know if the number is present in the slice or not, when both the first element and the nonexistent element return 0 as index?

**Update**
Note that the index can also be greater than the length of the slice so the proper way to find if an element is present in the slice is:

```
num := 1
n = sort.SearchInts(a, num) 
if n < len(a) && a[n] == num {
  // found
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the number you were looking for actually lives at the returned index. The [binary search routines in `sort`](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Search) are supposed to find the index where a value can be inserted if it's not already present.

E.g. a search for 100 in the slice in your example [will return 3](http://play.golang.org/p/sDVtc3v9Ax) because the value must be appended to the slice.

> the call `Search(len(data), func(i int) bool { return data[i] >= 23 })` returns the smallest index i such that `data[i] >= 23`. If the caller wants to find whether 23 is in the slice, it must test `data[i] == 23` separately.

Answer (score 3):

It may seem a functionally strange feature but it's documented :

> For instance, given a slice data sorted in ascending order, the call
>   Search(len(data), func(i int) bool { return data[i] >= 23 }) returns
>   the smallest index i such that data[i] >= 23.

The obvious solution is also documented :

> If the caller wants to
>   find whether 23 is in the slice, it must test data[i] == 23
>   separately.

Answer (score 1):

`SearchInts` searches for x in a sorted slice of ints and returns the index as specified by **Search**. `SearchInts` calls `Search` with a function:

```
func(i int) bool { return a[i] >= x }
```

Quoting from the Search doc:

> **Search** uses binary search to find and return the smallest index i in [0, n) at which f(i) is true, assuming that on the range [0, n),
>   f(i) == true implies f(i+1) == true. That is, Search requires that f
>   is false for some (possibly empty) prefix of the input range [0, n)
>   and then true for the (possibly empty) remainder; Search returns the
>   first true index. If there is no such index, Search returns n. Search
>   calls f(i) only for i in the range [0, n).

So basically you'll get back an index where the number you searched for should be inserted so the slice remains sorted.

Just check if at the returned index the number in the slice is identical to the one you searched for.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet is from the documentation:

```
x := 23
i := sort.Search(len(data), func(i int) bool { return data[i] >= x })
if i < len(data) && data[i] == x {
    // x is present at data[i]
} else {
    // x is not present in data,
    // but i is the index where it would be inserted.
}
```

http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Search

So you have to check `i < len(data) && data[i] == x` like you suggest.